# Telegram messenger Build Failed on Windows 10 Cannot find qt static plugin

Tags: windows, api, telegram

All Steps Done according to Build instructions for [Visual Studio 2015](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/doc/building-msvc.md)

Build Error

```
------ Build started: Project: MetaLang, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Moc'ing genlang.h...
moc_genlang.cpp
genlang.cpp
mlmain.cpp
Generating Code...
genlang.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct QStaticPlugin const __cdecl qt_static_plugin_QWindowsIntegrationPlugin(void)" (?qt_static_plugin_QWindowsIntegrationPlugin@@YA?BUQStaticPlugin@@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall StaticQWindowsIntegrationPluginPluginInstance::StaticQWindowsIntegrationPluginPluginInstance(void)" (??0StaticQWindowsIntegrationPluginPluginInstance@@QAE@XZ)

D:\TBuild\tdesktop\Win32\DebugLang\MetaLang.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Configuration

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
qt 5.6.0

Operating system:
Windows 10 x64
```

Comment: Fixed. before make qt. must use configure -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -opensource -confirm-license -static -I "D:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl\Release\include" -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib" -l Gdi32 -no-opengl -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS_DEBUG="D:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl_debug\Debug\lib\ssleay32.lib D:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl_debug\Debug\lib\libeay32.lib" OPENSSL_LIBS_RELEASE="D:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl\Release\lib\ssleay32.lib D:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl\Release\lib\libeay32.lib" -mp -nomake examples -nomake tests -platform win32-msvc2015

Comment: I am encountering the same issue not for Telegram but simply for a minimal static Windows Qt hello world. I am not using any build system, just Visual Studio itself. Do you know how to solve the issue with just Visual Studio? If not, could you elaborate what the fundamental issue is?